# How to alias a package for pkg-config?

Tags: python-3.x, cabal, haskell-stack, pkg-config, nix

I get this error:

```
Configuring cpython-3.4.0...
Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2: The pkg-config package 'python-3.4'
is required but it could not be found.
```

when I run (these Haskell-specific details might not be relevant) `stack build` in the course of setting up a Stack environment to test Haskell's CPython module.

I installed Python 3.4 via Nix. The command Nix chose is `python3.4`, so I made an alias from `python-3.4` to `python3.4` (by adding the line `alias python-3.4=python3.4` to my `.bashrc` file). But `pkg-config` still gives me the same error.

I am using KUbuntu (that's Ubuntu with KDE) version 16.04.

--

Per Mr. Grayson's comment, the variable $PKG_CONFIG_PATH appears to be empty:

```
jeff@jbb-lenovo:/nix$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH

jeff@jbb-lenovo:/nix$
```

Here are the path and contents of `python-3.4.pc`:

```
jeff@jbb-lenovo:/nix$ find . -name "python-3.4.pc"
./store/q5p46zmky5z6w54bh8gaqbgwkdbqk4qg-python3-3.4.7/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.4.pc
jeff@jbb-lenovo:/nix$ cat ./store/q5p46zmky5z6w54bh8gaqbgwkdbqk4qg-python3-3.4.7/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.4.pc
# See: man pkg-config
prefix=/nix/store/q5p46zmky5z6w54bh8gaqbgwkdbqk4qg-python3-3.4.7
exec_prefix=${prefix} libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: Python
Description: Python library
Requires: 
Version: 3.4
Libs.private: -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lncurses -lutil
Libs: -L${libdir} -lpython3.4m
Cflags: -I${includedir}/python3.4m
```

Comment: How did you make the alias?  Can you post the contents and full path of your `python-3.4.pc` file, and the full contents of `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`?

Comment: It's posted. Thank you, Mr. Grayson!

Comment: It sounds like you're just running `stack build` in a normal Ubuntu shell instead of inside a `nix-shell` or in a builder for a derivation built with `nix-build`.  The general way to build software with Nix is to make an expression for a derivation of it, and run `nix-build` to build that derivation.  Dependencies are not "installed" (that's a user environment concern), they are added to the `buildInputs` list in the arguments to `stdenv.mkDerivation`.

Comment: Installing something in your user environment is really meant for finished pieces of software, not libraries you are going to use to build other software.

Comment: I wasn't trying to use Nix for anything except installing Python 3.4. Do you mean that if I do that, I have to use Nix for Stack also?

Comment: Maybe you could get this strange arrangement to work if you set PKG_CONFIG_PATH correctly but it just seems like asking for trouble.  It would be more normal to install Python with apt-get if your stack utility isn't coming from Nix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the file python-3.4.pc to one of the directories `pkg-config` will look in.

To see all directories search:

```
$ pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
```

Then put the file into one of the folders listed.